# Firestore: get document back after adding it / updating it without additional network calls

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Is it possible to get document back after adding it / updating it without additional network calls with Firestore, similar to MongoDB?

I find it stupid to first make a call to add / update a document and then make an additional call to get it.

Comment: For which reason do you want to "get it back"? Could you please detail what is your exact goal?

Comment: To read back values of server timestamps for example. Or to read back values of entire document while making partial updates for example.

Comment: Ok, it is clearer now, thks. Which SDK are you using? Javascript one?

Comment: Yes, Firebase Admin SDK for Node.

Comment: I concur.  All we have is that it is so.  No rational reason.

Comment: I also find this stupid, and doubly so that this has not yet been rectified.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you have probably seen in the documentation of the Node.js (and Javascript) SDKs, this is not possible, neither with the methods of a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) nor with the one of a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference).

More precisely, the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) and [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) methods of a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) both return a Promise containing `void`, while the [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference)'s [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method returns a Promise containing a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

---

Side Note (in line with answer from darrinm below): It is interesting to note that with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest), when you [create a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.databases.documents), you get back (i.e. through the API endpoint response) a [`Document`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document) object.

Comment: So we have to make unnecessary calls to just get whatever we need from that document, affecting quota limitation

Comment: @Dani, this is how Firestore is designed at the time of writing. You may post a request for a new feature here https://firebase.uservoice.com/

Comment: done. Vote +1 pls: https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/48154985-firestore-return-document-when-it-gets-updated

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an arbitrary limitation of the the Firestore Javascript API. The Firestore REST API returns the updated document on the same call.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch

Comment: I'm facing the same limitation using Firebase package for Flutter

Answer (score 1):

When you add a document to Cloud Firestore, the server can affect the data that is stored. A few ways this may happen:

- If your data contains a marker for a server-side timestamp, the server will expand that marker into the actual timestamp.
- Your data data is not permitted according to your server-side security rules, the server will reject the write operation.

Since the server affects the contents of the `Document`, the client can't simply return the data that it already has as the new document. If you just want to show the data that you sent to the server in your client, you can of course do so by simply reusing the object you passed into `setData(...)`/`addDocument(data: ...)`.

Comment: That's precisely why I want the document back from Firestore but without the overhead of another network call, just how you can do it with MongoDB.

Comment: ^^ Precisely.  I was confused with Frank's irrelevant reply.  No one's speaking of optimism.

Comment: This is also affecting quota limitation if we need to do an extra read every time we update something. For my case, X people need to update the document, and all of them need to get the creator name. That means that I need to perform double of queries. At some point, if I need to pay, it's not because I really need it, it's because I'm making unnecessary calls to the database

Answer (score 0):

Well I was trying the same, but, I noticed that I already have the data in my code. So, instead of getting the document back, I decided to update my current object. Something like this:

```js
// Get the current document, e.g. some user
const querySnapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(docId)
    .get()

// Get the data, e.g. user data
let userData = querySnapshot.doc.data()
// Some business logic
...

if (condition) {
    // update document
    await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(docId)
        .update({phone: someNumber})
    
    // Update your current data
    userData.phone = someNumber
}
```

It saves a network call and accomplish what we intended.

Also, if the intention is to create a new document and then using it as a reference, you can store the newly created document's id in one variable:

```js
if (!userData) {
    const newUser = {name: someName, address: someAddress}
    const res = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .add({ ...newUser })
    userData = newUser
    userData.id = res.id
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I did this to get the ID of a new Document created, and then use it in something else.

```
Future<DocumentReference<Object>> addNewData() async {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final CollectionReference _userCollection = _firestore.collection('users');

  return await _userCollection 
    .add({ 'data': 'value' })
    .whenComplete(() => {
      // Show good notification
    })
    .catchError((e) {
      // Show Bad notification
    });
}
```

---

And here I obtain the ID:

```
await addNewData()
  .then((document) async {
    // Get ID
    print('ID Document Created ${document.id}');
  });
```

I hope it helps.