# How to retrieve added doc data in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have such code where I can get new inserted doc id:

```
db.collection("cities").add({
   name: "Tokyo",
   country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
   console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Is it possible to get data from ref?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: get document back after adding it / updating it without additional network calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678252/firestore-get-document-back-after-adding-it-updating-it-without-additional-ne)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can do it like this:**

```
.then(function(docRef) {
   db.collection("cities").doc(docRef.id).get()
     .then(snap => {
        console.log('Here is the document you wrote to', snap.data()
      })
})
```

Granted it requires another read which you probably didn't want

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
static async createUserPofile(uid) {
    const db = Firebase.firestore(),
        date = Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        data ={
            user_id: uid,
            creation_time: date,
            update_time: date
        },
        docRef = await db.collection("user_profiles").add(data),
        get = await docRef.get();
    return get.data();
}
```

Comment: The idea of getting after the add was expressed in @GrantSingleton's answer below.  Why not just accept that?  Also, I don't see what's being gained by getting and returning the `.data()`.  Don't you already have `data = {...}` in the line above?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sorry.  I wish that add would return a server timestamp.  I think it is too much to ask for the whole object as written, since triggers running after the add might change it.  Anyway, I'm upvoting the essence of the correct answer given first.

Answer (score 0):

We could retrieve added or updated data using this function:

```
function dataToObject(fDoc){
  return { ...fDoc.data(), id: fDoc.id }}
```

We should chain 'get' method to retrieve added or updated firestore data:

```
let fDoc = await db.collection("cities").add({
   name: "Tokyo",
   country: "Japan"
}).get()
```

Use it to transform your snapshot to an object:

```
const upserData = dataToObject(fDoc)
```